# How to purposely overscan a Unity Camera?

Tags: unity, shaders, camera

For many shader effects that use the scene color, we want this color to be displaced along the object plane. Think water, glass, heat distortion, etc.

However, of course, if this happens near the edges of the screen there is no valid data available to pull from beyond those edges.

Is there a way I can purposely overscan the camera so that there will be available data for these shaders to use?

Comment: Presumably you considered rendering to a RenderTexture larger than your display, and then cropping that RenderTexture to present to the screen?

Comment: @DMGregory Yes I did. Unfortunately to then use it as a proper distortion layer just for a specific object would require tricksy stacking of transparent render ordering. Not impossible, but I'd prefer a direct solution if it exists. Screen width and height are just numbers, after all. I can't imagine there's no way for a camera to push past them, I just have not been able to find it.

Comment: Want to walk us through this tricksy stacking method you're using, and we can look for opportunities to simplify it?